# is FrameworkElement rendered or not?

Tags: silverlight, frameworkelement

Is there a way to know is certain `FrameworkElement` was rendered to the screen. For example. I have two rectangles, and one overlap other. But I'm not sure about "how much" one overlap other.

So I need to know is user will see both rectangles, or will see only one, or will see one fully and one partially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of parent container it is, if both rectangles are inside `StackPanel` then they will not, you have to either make a custom container or use canvas as parent of these rectangles.

Then you can get LocalToScreen or such similar methods to get their absolute positions compared to screen or top parent window and find out whether they overlap or not.

Comment: Yes it's normal solution. But it's not too fast. In terms of speed. I just want to know is user see certain rectange or not. I actually don't need position of elements. Dose Silverlight have that kind of fuctionallity?